# Copy or Clone SQL table with constraints

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to create same structure of table in another table..

But it should create same table structure with all primary keys and indexes of that old table.

I tried below but it copies only columns.. not primary key nor indexes.

```
SELECT *
INTO dbo.NewTable
FROM dbo.ExistingTable
WHERE 1 = 2
```

How can I copy/clone that too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm posting you a part of a script i used to create a clone of a database, i removed some parts and it's missing FKs and indexes (but PKs are there, ignoring identity :P) but should give you a hint on how you could do it

beware: it's not optimised since i need to run it 1 time and not on a schedule, i just made it work with my databases :P fix it for your needs:

```
declare @DestinationSchema nvarchar(50) = 'frontier'
declare @SourceSchema nvarchar(50) = 'dbo'

select  so.name as TableName
        ,N'create table [' + @DestinationSchema + '].[' + so.name + '] (' + o.list + (case when kc.name IS NULL then '' else ' CONSTRAINT ' + kc.name  + ' PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ' + ' (' + LEFT(j.List, Len(j.List)-1) + '))' end) as TableScript
from    sys.objects so
cross apply
    (select 
        -- column name
        '  ['+cl.name+'] ' + 
        -- column type
        t.name + 
        -- type lenght
        (case t.name
            when 'sql_variant' then ''
            when 'text' then ''
            when 'ntext' then ''
            when 'bit' then '' 
            when 'int' then ''
            when 'tinyint' then ''
            when 'smallint' then ''
            when 'bigint' then ''
            when 'timestamp' then ''
            when 'date' then ''
            when 'smalldatetime' then ''
            when 'datetime' then ''
            when 'datetime2' then ''
            when 'real' then ''
            when 'float' then ''
            when 'time' then ''
            when 'decimal' then '(' + cast(cl.[precision] as varchar) + ', ' + cast(cl.scale as varchar) + ')'
            else '('+ (case when cl.max_length = -1 then 'MAX' else cast(cl.max_length as varchar) end) +')' end) + ' ' +
        -- nullable
        (case when cl.is_nullable = 0 then 'NOT ' else '' end ) + 'NULL,'
     from sys.columns cl
            inner join sys.types t on cl.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
     where object_id = so.object_id
     order by cl.column_id
    for xml path('')
    ) o (list)
inner join sys.schemas sch on so.[schema_id] = sch.[schema_id] AND sch.name = @SourceSchema
left join sys.key_constraints kc on so.[object_id] = kc.parent_object_id AND kc.[type] = 'PK' AND kc.[schema_id] = so.[schema_id]
cross apply
    (select N'[' + col.name + '], '
     from   sys.columns col 
                inner join sys.indexes i on col.[object_id] = i.[object_id] and i.is_primary_key = 1
                inner join sys.index_columns ic on ic.object_id = so.object_id and ic.column_id = col.column_id and ic.index_id = i.index_id
     where  col.[object_id] = so.[object_id]
     order by ic.key_ordinal
     for xml path('')) j (list)
cross apply
    (select N'[Destination].[' + col.name + '] = [Source].[' + col.name + '] AND '
     from   sys.columns col 
                inner join sys.indexes i on col.[object_id] = i.[object_id] and i.is_primary_key = 1
                inner join sys.index_columns ic on ic.object_id = so.object_id and ic.column_id = col.column_id and ic.index_id = i.index_id
     where  col.[object_id] = so.[object_id]
     order by ic.key_ordinal
     for xml path('')) k (list)     
where
    so.[type] = 'U'
order by
    so.name
```