# Copy a table with constraints in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

When I execute the following query I could make a copy of a table without constraints

```
Select * into B from A
```

how to copy a table with constraints by SQL query?

Comment: You can execute the script of this table, during this you can check advanced settings that `include indexes`, `include foreign keys`, `include constraints`, `include drop table` and etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copy or Clone SQL table with constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451716/copy-or-clone-sql-table-with-constraints)

Comment: You can't copy or clone exported FK contraints (other tables that point to this one). What do you want to do in these cases?

Comment: I need only primary key constraints

Answer (score -1):

Try below Query:

```
SELECT *
INTO New Table  
FROM old table
WHERE Constraints
```

Example:

```
SELECT *
INTO Employee3  
FROM Employee  
WHERE [EMP Id] > 1
```

Comment: constraints not copied